# how to build hyperledger fabric with gccgo

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, gccgo

Is there a way to build hyperledger fabric using gccgo? I want to do this in order to use -finstrument-functions option of gcc to trace function calls. But I encountered two problems. My steps are as follows.

1. find the build command

> make -n release
>
> echo "Building release/linux-amd64/bin/configtxgen for
>   linux-amd64"
>
> mkdir -p release/linux-amd64/bin CGO_CFLAGS=" "
>
> GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o
>   /home/yiifburj/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/release/linux-amd64/bin/configtxgen
>   -tags "nopkcs11" -ldflags "-X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen/metadata.Version=1.1.0"
>   github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen

2. modify the build command to use gccgo

> CGO_CFLAGS=" " GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -compiler gccgo -o /home/yiifburj/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/release/linux-amd64/bin/configtxgen
>   -tags "nopkcs11" -gccgoflags "-X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen/metadata.Version=1.1.0"
>   github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen
>
> #github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bccsp/factory
>
> bccsp/factory/pluginfactory.go:12:8: error: import file ‘plugin’ not
>   found
>    "plugin"
>
> bccsp/factory/pluginfactory.go:56:15: error: reference to undefined name
>
> ‘plugin’   plug, err :=
>   plugin.Open(config.PluginOpts.Library)

First, as above, "plugin" couldn't be found when gccgo is invoked by go build.
Another one is how to pass ldflags -X when use gccgo? It seems that -X is a parameter only invalid in gc tools not gccgo.

Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the correct version of GCC in order to get support for the versions of Go supported by the various Fabric releases.

- Fabric 1.1 requires Go 1.9.x
- Fabric 1.2.x requires Go 1.10.x
- The upcoming Fabric 1.3 also requires Go 1.10

gccgo did not support Go 1.9 (GCC 7 had support for Go 1.8).  GCC 8 adds support for Go 1.10.

So you should use Fabric v1.2 and GCC 8.